# Codeigniter / PHPexcel Set arabic title in properties of xls file

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding, phpexcel, arabic

I am working on my web project using Codeigniter. I want to generate an excel file by setting the data in the file, for now that's cool.

but I have a problem is that the site uses Arabic as a primary language, and I would set the title and description in the properties of excel file.

when I open the excel file and I open the properties, it does not display the title and description in Arabic, but like this:

> Ã™Â‡Ã™Â„ Ã˜ÂªÃ˜Â¹Ã˜ÂªÃ™Â‚Ã˜Â¯ Ã˜Â£Ã™Â† Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã™Â†Ã˜Â¸Ã˜Â§Ã™Â… Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã˜Â³Ã™ÂˆÃ˜Â±Ã™ÂŠ Ã˜Â³Ã™ÂŠÃ˜Â³Ã˜ÂªÃ˜Â¬Ã™ÂŠÃ˜Â¨ Ã™Â„Ã˜Â´Ã˜Â±Ã™ÂˆÃ˜Â· Ã˜Â®Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â·Ã™ÂÃ™ÂŠ Ã™Â†Ã˜Â³Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â¡ Ã™ÂˆÃ˜Â£Ã˜Â·Ã™ÂÃ˜Â§Ã™Â„ Ã™Â…Ã™Â† Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„Ã˜Â¹Ã™Â„Ã™ÂˆÃ™ÂŠÃ™Â†Ã˜ÂŸ

I tried utf8_decode function but it does not work

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the excel file is saved version 5, then I should Register with the 2007 version (. xlsx) and the Arabic values ​​appear correctly in file properities:

```
$obj_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
$obj_writer->save('php://output');
```